# Как я могу получить значение по умолчанию?

Tags: java, spring

Как получить значение по умолчанию (28)? Вот более полный код на github https://github.com/Teemitze/test

```java
    package ru.otus.spring01.dao;

    import ru.otus.spring01.domain.Person;

    public class PersonDaoSimple implements PersonDao {

        public Person findByName(String name) {
            return new Person(name, 18);
        }

        public void setDefaultAge(String defaultAge) {
        }
    }
```

spring.xml

```xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


            <bean id="personDao" class="ru.otus.spring01.dao.PersonDaoSimple">
                <property name="defaultAge" value="28"/>
            </bean>

            <bean id="personService" class="ru.otus.spring01.service.PersonServiceImpl">
                <constructor-arg name="dao" ref="personDao"/>
            </bean>

    </beans>
```

Comment: добавьте поле и в методе setDefaultAge присваивайте ему значение

Comment: Тогда придётся создать конструктор в котором будет только name? Но на выходе тогда получу:
name: null age: 0

Comment: Не совсем. У вас метод setDefaultAge вызовется раньше, чем метод findByName. поэтому на момент создание Person у вас уже будет и возраст и имя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже писали в комментарии, вам нужно инициализировать поле и через сеттер передать ему значение из xml

```
public class PersonDaoSimple implements PersonDao {
    private int defaultAge=18;

    public Person findByName(String name) {
        return new Person(name, defaultAge);
    }

    public void setDefaultAge(int defaultAge) {
    this.defaultAge=defaultAge;
    }
}
```